How does Bloomberg calculate reset rates for a fixed to floating swap?
I believe Bloomberg uses daily compounded sofr rates to calculate the reset rate for a cashflow period. My question is when I take the data from S490 curve - USD SOFR curve directly and linearly interpolate to get the daily rates and then calculate daily compounded sofr my numbers are off by quite a bit.
Does Bloomberg uses forward rates for sofr ? Should I calculate the forward rates through bootstrapping and then interpolate the daily rates? I'm currently doing quarterly reset so I take 3m rate , then take 6m rate , calculate the rate between 3m and 6m and assign it to 6m tenor and then use those rates to interpolate daily rates and then calculate daily compounded sofr to arrive at reset rates? Kindly please help me with this.

It's daily reset. You might find this answer helpful. Generally, it's not how Bloomberg does it, just how SOFR works.

What rate is used depends on your settings. There is Bos or lookback, see here for details.

Thank you for answering. I'm using S490 USD SOFR as my input curve which is used for forward and discounting. 3M USOSFRC is my Index. I'm trying to replicate SWPM functionality in python, I want to arrive at quarterly reset rates given S490 curve tenors. I'm interpolating s490 rates linearly to get daily rates and doing daily compounding for the first 3 months to arrive at reset rates for 2nd payment and so on, they are off. First reset rate is given from 3M tenor rate from S490 curve. Can you please help me with the mathematical formula for arriving at reset rates from USD SOFR tenor rates.

It's best to start by looking at ICVS. Tye help page has a document explaining what Interpolations are available. You will also see what your default is there. Afterwards, look at rateslib.
